# Raspicam stops working after one year

Tags: pi-4, raspicam

I am using two raspberries (rpi 4) with cameras (HQ cam) to make a timelapse of a house build. The raspberries have been mounted without any hardware changes for over 2 years now. They are in a remote location, connected to the network, and I access them using SSH.

Yesterday, the `raspicam` command that is scheduled to run every minute started hanging on one of the raspberries, and no pictures were taken since. A similar issue had already happened in the past with the same raspberry, so I logged in to check it.

The uptime of the raspberry was 364 days yesterday. While reading old notes, I saw that last year, when the same issue happened, the uptime was also 364 days. This seems like a peculiar coincidence.

When running `raspistill -w 1280 -h 720 -o test1.jpg` , the process creates the output file `test1.jpq~`, but never writes to it. The file remains empty even after a couple of minutes. The process never exits and doesn't output to stdin or stderr.

The second raspberry didn't encounter similar camera issues yet, but it often suffers from power outages, so it has not yet reached the uptime.

The previous issue was resolved by a reboot, however, I would like to understand the reasons behind the issue. I have tried disabling and enabling the camera module in `raspi-config`, but it didn't help.

Are there some diagnostics I can run or some logs I should check? Is there a way to resolve the issue without rebooting the raspberry?

```
pi@cam1:~ $ vcgencmd version
Aug 31 2021 14:53:42 
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version 67615e950e1e28b92dfae6303cf7a8b879a8908f (clean) (release) (start_x)

pi@cam1:~ $ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: cam1
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 46ccd4bd09da490b827c8ad81c001ef6
           Boot ID: 11f937a5be914f8aaf2d85b256e76a0a
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 5.10.60-v7l+
      Architecture: arm
```

Comment: You should now be using the `libcamera` on RaspiOS Bullseye or Bookworm pieces if you want to remain supported.

Comment: *"I would like to understand the reasons behind the issue"* -> If you mean this is supposed to happen but you don't know why, I'd say it almost certainly isn't supposed to happen and finding the reason is probably not going to be easy; I think very very few people will actually have been affected by it and most of the ones that have probably did not notice the 364 day uptime correlation.